# Display images in a loop using bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to display images one after the other automatically using bash. 
However if I use a command like this. It doesn't close the last image before opening the next.

```
while read p; 
    do eog $p; 
    sleep 2; 
done < filelist.txt
```

Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the `PID` of the `eog` process and kill it before the next:

```
while read p; 
    do eog $p &;
    EOG_PID=$!
    sleep 2;
    kill "$EOG_PID"
done < filelist.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible to grep that process id automatically?

Comment: Yes, we could `pgrep eog` or just `killall eog` but this method (start in background, get pid with `$!`) allows us to only kill the `eog` we want — automatically.

Comment: Ah ok. I see. Yes it seems to work, thank you, although it's a little bit slow but I guess its just not the perfect way to display images :). Thanks anyway

Comment: @mcExchange If all the images are in the same directory, then you could use `eog`'s builtin slideshow.